# Delphi TForm constructor

Tags: delphi

I have already found something on stackoverflow but it doesn't really solve my doubt. I know that the correct way to create an object is, after the creation, surround the code in a try-finally block. But what about:

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  a := TClassX.Create;
end;
```

And then call:

```
procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  a.Free;
end;
```

Where `a: TClassX;` is a public declaration inside `TForm3` class. Should I create the constructor and the destructor for the form, or I can use the code above? Is it safe?

Comment: If the class supports owners (is a descendant of TControl or is it TComponent?), then you could also use *a:=TClassX.Create(Self)* and let the destructor of your form free the "a" instance. You then wouldn't need to bother with the a.Free part (it would be done by the TForm's destructor).

Comment: I would recommend that you **don't** declare `a: TClassX` in the public section. It prevents encapsulation, and as the code base gets larger, the overall application becomes more complex. And it will become more difficult to confidently reason about the correctness of your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The try/finally is there, or at least something equivalent. It just exists outside your code, higher up the call stack. Something like:

```
Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
try
  // do stuff
finally
  Form1.Free;
end;
```

Your `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` handlers are called from the constructor and destructor, respectively, and so are protected.

So long as everybody plays by the rules nothing leaks. And the rules here are that objects created in the constructor and to be destroyed in the destructor. Whoever actually creates the object is responsible to ensure that it is destroyed no matter what. But that's the task of the consumer of your class rather than you.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with this events some time ago so I would not recommend to use *OnCreate/OnDestroy* events in your application. Here are just some cases I remember:

- VCL by default handles exception from *OnCreate/OnDestroy* events. Actually if `a:=TClassX.Create;` will generate an exception, it will be shown by application exception handler but the form will be created successfully keeping "a" variable equals to nil. This may lead to Access Violations if you try to access this variable later.
- Depending on OldCreateOrder these events may be called either from *constructor/destructor* or from *AfterConstruction/BeforeDestruction* methods. It may also lead to Access Violations if you occasionally change *OldCreateOrder* in form descendants

And even more, it looks strange for me when you are using events instead of virtual functions. In most cases events are used to delegate the functionality to another objects (for example you assign a form's method to a button's OnClick event).